# How can I structure my data?

Tags: c#, sql

I have two classes(Book,Software) that inherit from the Product class. these two classes have some fields that are different from each other. if i am to save the data for both these classes to a single table it would cause some columns to have null values.

if i save the data into different tables(Books table and Software Table) and then wanted to view this data in a single gridview, would i have to join the data and then load it to the gridview?

I would like to add 2 more classes(IndividualCustomer, WholesaleCustomer) later on which will inherit the Customer class in the same manner as mentioned above.

please guide me towards the best approach.thank you

Comment: what is the structure of your Tables / Database is this do you have any true relationships setup ??

Comment: no, i havent setup any relationships yet, i need advice on how to approach the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no C# programmer, but I'd go with something like

```
`products` table
 - product_id (pk)
 - title
 - price
 - etc

`products_software` table
 - software_id (pk)
 - product_id (foreign key, relates to a product_id)
 - serial_number
 - storage_media

`products_books` table
 - book_id (pk)
 - product_id (foreign key, relates to a product_id)
 - pages
 - author
```

Comment: and if i wanted to view the combined data in a single gridview, how would i query the database?

Comment: I can't give you a C# answer, but the SQL could look something like `SELECT * FROM products p INNER JOIN products_software ps ON p.product_id = ps.product_id UNION SELECT * FROM products p INNER JOIN products_books pb ON p.product_id = pb.product_id`

Comment: With this design you can have many Books per every Book Product. For the purpose of representing inheritance in a relational DB it should be better 1:1 association than 1:N association.

Answer (score 3):

In situations  like this I create three tables: Product, Book and Software.

In Product I'll put the PK and all common fields; in Book the same PK and book specific fields; the same as Book for Software.

The associations between these kind of tables should be 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

The Books and Softwares are not different Products they are just different Categories.

I would create several tables:
Products
Categories
Properties
PropertiesToCategories
PropertiesToProducts

In this form you can attach some property to each category, example: Books has Author, Title, Publisher

When you want to add a new Product you should choose first it's Category and then you can attach the available (for Books: Author, Title, Publisher) properties to your new product.